# ServiceMix ESB as Bus or Container?

Tags: osgi, esb, apache-servicemix

Should we use ServiceMix ESB as bus (i.e. communication channels) or as container to host services?

My current company host services (JMS/SOAP/RESTFUL etc, built by Java) in their own separate containers/servers etc, then each of these communicate to each other via the ServiceMix ESB, by adding extra bindings.

1. Is this a correct approach?
2. Should we migrate all existing services to become OSGI bundles, then host on ServiceMix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say it depends more on your current system land-scape. How do you handle failover and such. I personally would have all my service on that machine and if a routing is needed would try to do an "in-memory" routing instead of doing external service calls, would be much faster. On the other hand this again depends purely on how your application stack is working and if you have "time-critical" service calls that would perform better if run inside the same jvm. So actually there can't be a "silver-bullet" approach on this. As usual it depends ...